# In MVC, does passing a model property to an action automatically retrieves that property value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Lets say we have a controller calle `Home` with an action `Index`. The associated view to that action is also called `Index`

Now lets say we have a model called `DataModel` which is referenced using Razor in the `Index` view using `@model ProjectName.Model.DataModel`. Now below is the declaration of the classes :

**Model**

```
public class DataModel
{
   int property1 {get; set;}
   string ReturnURL {get ; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController :  Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string returnUrl)
    {
        var model = new DataModel 
        {
            ReturnURL = returnUrl;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

When the `SomeAction` is called, it is passed a string. I was reading a [tutorial](http://kristianguevara.net/creating-your-asp-net-mvc-5-application-from-scratch-for-beginners-using-entity-framework-6-and-identity-with-crud-functionalities/) where the value of the string is not empty. I'd understand is we passed directly a `DataModel` object but just one property .... I dont get it (also we know its a property because it's the same name as the property...upper/lower case is not respected)

In the tutorial, the actions that used that single string parameters are `Login` and `GetRedirectUrl` in part 6 of the tutorial...

That why I asked if passing a model property to an action automatically retrieves that property value.  Or could you kindly explain me from where the parameter string `returnUrl` gets its value from.

Comment: `returnUrl` is taken from a query string. It looks like `http://domain:port/controller/action?returnUrl=/home`. Try read about model binding in MVC.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov are u saying that any action causing a query string will have a generic parameter `returnUrl` and also that generic parameter can be passed/accessed in any action of the controller/action/view causing the query string ?

Comment: No, it appears only for non-authenticated requests after authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of returnUrl comes from the model binder. Depending on how you have your routing setup.

It could be either query string:

> http://siteroot/someaction?returnUrl=YOUR_RETURN_URL_HERE

or via a route

> http://siteroot/someaction/YOUR_RETURN_URL_HERE

Like I say it depends on your route config. Also bear in mind that the returnUrl would need to be http encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access an action which is marked with `[Authorize]` attribute and you are not logged in it will redirect you to login page which is set to `Configuration` class and as a parameter it will supply you the `controller/action/` url but you can see it encoded.

[image: An example image here]